# Return SVG object in filter

Tags: angularjs, svg

I am creating a filter that is intended to change weather id code with corresponding image.

HTML looks like this:

```
<span ng-bind-html="weather.today.weather[0].id | weatherIcon"></span>
```

When I use `img` tag it works just fine:

```
.filter('weatherIcon', function() {
    return function() {
        var template = `<img src="img/weather-icons-set/CLOUDS/CLOUDS/001lighticons-02.svg">`; 
        return template;
    }
})
```

But I would like to embed my svg to be able changing colors etc. Unfortunately with `object` tag it doesn't work at all:

```
.filter('weatherIcon', function() {
    return function() {
        var template = `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/weather-icons-set/CLOUDS/CLOUDS/001lighticons-02.svg" width="100" height="100"></object>`; 
        return template;
    }
})
```

I've also tried to put `ng-include` in filter return, but it also failed. Can you tell me, what is wrong with returning `<object>` in a filter, or give me a hint for another approach?

Answer (score 1):

Your SVG image might define `fill` or `stroke` properties and it might be the cause of your problem, you should check first inside your file.

Otherwise I'll just give you an hint for another approach I'm using. Just note that you'll need to modify your SVG images.

You can use the nodes `<use>` and `<symbol>` in SVG ([Use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use), [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol)).

Instead of your `span`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
    <use xlink:href="{{PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE + ID}}" style="fill: YOUR_COLOR;"></use>
</svg>
```

The subtility is here: `xlink:href="{{PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE + ID}}"`. The SVG image you use must define an Id and be inside a `<symbol>` node.

e.g.:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="myId" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
        [...img here...]
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Then you'll use it like this in your `<use>` node: `xlink:href="img/weather-icons-set/CLOUDS/CLOUDS/001lighticons-02.svg#myId"`

Make sure your images don't override the properties `fill` or `stroke`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ultimately I used a web-font instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I used a web-font instead. My filter looks like this:

```
.filter('weatherIcon', function($sce) {
    return function(weatherCode, isNight) {

        var template;
        var iconCode;

        ...

        template = `<span class="icon" data-icon="${iconCode}"></span>`
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(template);
    }
})
```